# Convert a video to frames with opencv in Spyder (Windows 10)

Tags: python, image, opencv, spyder

I am trying to convert a video into a series of frames with the help of opencv in Spyder on Windows 10. I did like I was told in order to be able to import cv2, by copying the cv2.pyd into the library folder of Anaconda.

I tried running this code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os

# Playing video from file:
vidcap  = cv2.VideoCapture('example.mp4')
success,image = vidcap.read()
# image is an array of array of [R,G,B] values

count = 0; 
while success:
    print count
    success,image = vidcap.read()
    cv2.imwrite("frame%d.jpg" % count, image)     # save frame as JPEG file

    if cv2.waitKey(10) == 27:                     # exit if Escape is hit
        break

    count += 1
```

But I don't get any error and nothing happens.

Comment: Instead of `while success:`, can you try `while vidcap.isOpened():` instead?